# Swift unwrapping for multiple optionals

Tags: swift, option-type, unwrap

I thought this was possible but can't seem to get it to work. I'm sure I'm just being stupid. Im trying to output a formatted address in the form of

```
"one, two, three"
```

from a set of optional components (one, two, three). If "two" is nil then output would be

`"one, three"`

```
let one: String?
let two: String?
let three: String?

one = "one"
two = nil
three = "three"

if let one = one,
        two = two,
        three = three {
     print("\(one),\(two),\(three)")
}
```

Comment: `print("\(one ?? ""),\(two ?? ""),\(three ?? "")")`, maybe.

Comment: What output do you expect if some but not all variables are nil? `if one ?? two ?? three != nil` checks if at least one is non-nil, but does not unwrap. `[one, two, three].flatMap { $0 }` gives a list of the non-nil variables, unwrapped.

Comment: I voted to close as "unclear what you asking", but I will be happy to revoke the vote if the question is updated.

Comment: @MartinR sorry for any confusion. Im trying to output a formatted address (in the form of "address, city, country) from a set of optional components (address, city, country etc). If city is nil then output would be "address, country". It looks your flatMap idea would work though

Comment: @Danny: I have retracted my closing vote, but you should update the *question* itself to clarify your problem (nobody reads all comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're attempting to print the non-`nil` values as a comma-separated list, then I think @MartinR's suggestion of using `flatMap()` is the best:

```
let one: String?
let two: String?
let three: String?

one = "one"
two = nil
three = "three"

let nonNils = [one, two, three].flatMap { $0 }
if !nonNils.isEmpty {
    print(nonNils.joinWithSeparator(","))
}
```

Output:

> ```
> one,three
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I dont know why you need this, but take it =)

```
if let _ = one ?? two ?? three {
    print("\(one),\(two),\(three)")
}
```

Comment: `if one != nil || two != nil || three != nil` would be more readable considering you are not really unwrapping but only checking for `nil`.

Comment: @Sulthan In my solution there is less letters, and anyway nobody need it in practice =)

Comment: Sometimes it is. Remember recursive functions. Though, Martin R answer most correct & elegant.

Comment: Less letters, less lines of code is never a good metric. Code complexity and readability are better metrics.

Comment: My case is more readable, your case - big and confusing; though it tiny faster, you will never can feel it in this situation, thats what I mean. Nobody think that reduce lines/letters can result better quality of code by itself.